# Firebase: Como excluir un atributo para que no se guarde en la BD

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Tengo la siguiente clase que uso para crear objetos que luego guardo en una BD Firebase Real Time:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

public class Empresa {

  @Exclude
  private String key;
  private String Codigo;
  private String Nombre;
```

Lo que necesito es que únicamente se guarden en la BD los campos `codigo` y `nombre`.

He encontrado páginas donde se indica que con `@Exclude` se excluye un atributo de la clase para que no se guarde en la BD, pero en mi caso no funciona y guardar los tres atributos.

¿Como se puede hacer?
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que *no se guarde*? ¿Te refieres a que no se mapee a una instancia de la clase cuando usas `toObject` o lo que estás es guardando datos desde Android en Firebase? Dinos también si usas Real Time Database o Firestore.

Comment: ¿Probaste a poner la anotación `@Exclude` también en los métodos `getKey()` y `setKey()`?

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano lo que me faltaba era poner los ```@Exclude``` en los getters y setters.  Ahora funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tenemos una clase POJO de la cual no queremos que se persistan en la BD alguno de sus atributos miembros debemos anteponer, tanto al atributo como a sus métodos getter y setter, la anotación `@Exclude`

Como ejemplo a continuación pueden ver tres atributos de la clase `Empresa` de los cuales únicamente dos atributos se guardaran en la BD:

```
  public class Empresa {

  @Exclude
  private String key;
  private String Codigo;
  private String Nombre;

  public Empresa(String codigo, String nombre) {
    Codigo = codigo;
    Nombre = nombre;
  }

  public Empresa(String key, String codigo, String nombre) {
    this.key = key;
    Codigo = codigo;
    Nombre = nombre;
  }

  public Empresa() {
  }

  @Exclude
  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  @Exclude
  public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public String getCodigo() {
    return Codigo;
  }

  public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    Codigo = codigo;
  }

  public String getNombre() {
    return Nombre;
  }

  public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    Nombre = nombre;
  }

  @Exclude
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return Nombre;
  }
}
```

Comment: He votado en contra porque no estoy de acuerdo con tu solución. En Firebase se recomienda [tener un constructor vacío y un getter y setter para cada miembro de la clase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write). ¿Por qué no optas por ese estándar y luego usas `@Exclude` como está indicado, también en los getter y setter? Revisa el Log porque puede que haciéndolo así te esté dando advertencias en el Log de que la propiedad tal no tiene setter y eso no es bueno.

Comment: La clase tiene un constructor vacío y los getters y setters por cada uno de los miembros de la clase.  Esa parte esta correcta.   Lo que me faltaba por poner era los ```@Exclude``` en el getter y setter del miembro que no quiero guardar en la BD ya que únicamente lo había puesto en el propio miembro y por eso fallaba.

Comment: Sugiero entonces que edites tu auto-respuesta indicando la solución que has implementado, para que quede como referencia. Recuerda que la finalidad del sitio también es ayudar a futuros usuarios con un problema similar.

Comment: No hace falta que uses @Exclude en variables privadas como lo que usas al principio, ya que no accedes a esas variables en otro lugar, si esta bien en metodos de acceso publico que no queres obtener desde otras clases, la idea de mandar ciertos datos a Firebase es creando constructores que almacenen los datos que queres enviar, +1

Comment: Pero el usar el ```@Exclude``` en la primera variable y en sus métodos getter y setter es porque no quiero que esa variable se guarde en la BD cuando hago un ```setValue(empresa)``` en FireBase.  Las otras dos si quiero que se guarden en la BD, por lo cual no tienen el ```@Exclude```